# apt-get update перестал работать

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Failed to exec method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
Failed to exec method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https returned an error code (100)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https returned an error code (100)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
```

В чём причина и как лечить помимо способа [переустановки](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551796/failed-to-exec-method-usr-lib-apt-methods-http)?

#### Обновлено

apt update и aptitude update выдают аналогичный результат.

Версия Debian 8.8.

В sources apt репозиториев имеется два по https протоколу:

```
https://deb.nodesource.com 
https://repo.skype.com
```

При изменении версии https на http для deb.nodesource.com, apt-get update срабатывает, при условии что repo.skype.com закомментирован полностью.

При изменении версии https на http для repo.skype.com, apt-get update начинает работать но зависает на этапе получения заголовков:

```
Ign http://repo.skype.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://repo.skype.com stable Release.gpg
Ign http://repo.skype.com stable Release
100% [Waiting for headers]
```

Думаю, для репозитория Skype это связано с предстоящим прекращением поддержки старых версий (текущих то бишь), под Linux.

#### Итого

apt-get update сработал при вышеописанных операциях, также выполнен apt-get upgrade, но при возвращении вышеуказанных репозиториев обратно на https версию, также получаем ошибки, которые указаны в вопросе. Таким образом обходное решение найдено, но причины неясны.

Comment: `apt update` и `aptitude update` — аналогичная ситуация? кстати, уточните версию дистрибутива (`$ lsb_release -r`).

Comment: `/usr/lib/apt/methods/https` принадлежит пакету `apt-transport-https`. у меня на машинах он нигде и не стоит. у вас где-то в sources используется какой-нибудь репозиторий с доступом по https? попробуйте его временно отключить (или исправить на http, если сервер не против).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/294532/416190 // ign — «ничего нового»

Comment: так закомментируйте эти строки со всеми этими левыми репозиториями. чтобы **официальные** репозитории заработали, и можно было обновить пакеты в системе. а после обновления, глядишь, и исчезнут ошибки, связанные с невозможностью проверки сертификатов.